# PHP-FPM Not loading Environment Variables from /etc/environment

Tags: linux, nginx, php-fpm

I have environment variables set in `/etc/environment`. `printenv` shows them. However, php-fpm isn't seeing them. I have uncommented `clear_env = no` in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` - this exposes SOME env vars to php-fpm (such as PATH), but none of those set in `/etc/environment`. Also, if I try to reference the `/etc/environment` environment variables in `www.conf`, like this: `env[FOO] = $SOMEVAR` (where SOMEVAR is set in `/etc/environment`), php has the envar FOO set to an empty value.

I'm by no means a Linux expert, but it seems to me that however php-fpm runs doesn't "use" the envars set in `/etc/environment`. Maybe? Please help.

Running Amazon Linux

THANKS!
Adam

UPDATE:

```
sudo chkconfig --list php-fpm
php-fpm         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Dan, does that help? This is how php-fpm starts on reboot. Thanks!

Comment: how is php-fpm started?

Comment: Why do you believe that php-fpm would ever read `/etc/environment`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton welp how/where else would I set environment variables that can be read by both php-fpm and php cli?

Comment: AFAIK `/etc/environment` is a PAM-specific thing that applies only to user sessions when they log in. I've also never seen a system where anyone has actually tried to use it for anything... For your current problem I would use Amazon Linux 2, and put your desired environment variables into a systemd override.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *php-fpm* service to load `/etc/environment`, then you can add following line in the *Service* section:

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
```